# 2 Eventos con un AND condition en Jquery? Cómo?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito ejecutar un doble evento con jquery pero necesito que sea con condicion AND.
Osea, sería si el mouse esta apretado y el mouse está sobre el elemento hacer tal cosa...
Creo que el evento ".on" no me sirve ya que me ejecuta si pasa uno o el otro, y necesito que sea si se cumplen las 2 cosas.
La realidad es que estoy haciendo un pixel art y cuando hago click en un pixel lo pinta, pero si mantengo apretado no pinta, solo el primer pixel que hice click. Mouseover o hover me sirven a medias porque cumplen la función de pintar tipo pincel pero no mientras hago click si no siempre y yo necesito mientras el click esté apretado.
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné haciendo un booleano así,

```
let mousePresionado;

$(grillaPixeles).mousedown(function () {
  mousePresionado = true;
});
$(document).mouseup(function () {
  mousePresionado = false;
});

pintar = () => {
  $(grillaPixeles).find('div').mouseover(function () {
    if (mousePresionado) {
      $(this).css('background-color', $(indicadorDeColor).css('background-color'));
    }
  })
}
pintar();
```

Answer (score 0):

"si el mouse esta apretado y el mouse está sobre el elemento" es el evento `click()`

```
$(grillaPixeles).find('div').click(function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', $(indicadorDeColor).css('background-color'));
})
```

Tambien puedes usar el atributo `onClick` de HTML:

**HTML**

```
<div id="miDiv" onClick="pintar($(this))">
```

**JS**

```
function pintar(elemento) {
    elemento.css('background-color', $(indicadorDeColor).css('background-color'))
}
```